# How to oversample image dataset using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, imblearn

I am working on a multiclass classification problem with an unbalanced dataset of images(different class). I tried `imblearn` library, but it is not working on the image dataset.

I have a dataset of images belonging to 3 class namely A,B,C. A has 1000 data, B has 300 and C has 100. I want to oversample class B and C, so that I can avoid data imbalance. Please let me know how to oversample the image dataset using python.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  In particular, be detailed about what you've attempted ("I tried imblearn library" is far too general) and what's wrong ("it is not working" is not a problem specification).  We can't fix a problem when we don't know what you have to accomplish, what you did, and what went wrong.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.

Comment: Thanks @Prune for letting me know the guidelines. Could you please let me know how to do oversampling for data with images. I have a dataset of images belonging to 3 class namely A,B,C. A has 1000 data, B has 300 and C has 100. I want to oversample class B and C. So that I could avoid data imbalance. Please let me know. Thanks once again for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it seems  `imblearn.over_sampling` resamples just 2d dims inputs. So one way to oversample your image dataset by this library is to use reshaping alongside it, you can:

- reshape your images
- oversample them
- again reshape the new dataset to
  the first dims

consider you have an image dataset of `size (5000, 28, 28, 3) and dtype of nd.array`, following the above instructions, you can use the solution below:

```
# X : current_dataset
# y : labels

from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
reshaped_X = X.reshape(X.shape[0],-1)

#oversampling
oversample = RandomOverSampler()
oversampled_X, oversampled_y  = oversample.fit_resample(reshaped_X , y)

# reshaping X back to the first dims
new_X = oversampled_X.reshape(-1,28,28,3)
```

hope that was helpful!