# Oversampling of image data for keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, oversampling

I am working on Kaggle competition and trying to solve a multilabel classification problem with keras.

My dataset is highly imbalanced. I am familiar with this concept and did it for simple machine learning datasets, but now sure how to deal with both images and csv data.

There are a couple of questions, but they did not help me.

[Use SMOTE to oversample image data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53666759/use-smote-to-oversample-image-data)

[How to oversample image dataset using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532069/how-to-oversample-image-dataset-using-python)

```
Class
No finding            25462
Aortic enlargement     5738
Cardiomegaly           4345
Pleural thickening     3866
Pulmonary fibrosis     3726
Nodule/Mass            2085
Pleural effusion       1970
Lung Opacity           1949
Other lesion           1771
Infiltration            997
ILD                     792
Calcification           775
Consolidation           441
Atelectasis             229
Pneumothorax            185
```

I am trying to do oversampling, but not sure how to approach it. I have 15000 `png` images and `train.csv` dataset, which looks like:

```
image_id    class_name  class_id    rad_id  x_min   y_min   x_max   y_max   width   height
0   50a418190bc3fb1ef1633bf9678929b3    No finding  14  R11 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2332    2580
1   21a10246a5ec7af151081d0cd6d65dc9    No finding  14  R7  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2954    3159
2   9a5094b2563a1ef3ff50dc5c7ff71345    Cardiomegaly    3   R10 691.0   1375.0  1653.0  1831.0  2080    2336
3   051132a778e61a86eb147c7c6f564dfe    Aortic enlargement  0   R10 1264.0  743.0   1611.0  1019.0  2304    2880
4   063319de25ce7edb9b1c6b8881290140    No finding  14  R10 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2540    3072
```

How to attack this problem, when I have images and csv?

When I converted data, it looks like:

```
                               Images               Class
56     d106ec9b305178f3da060efe3191499a.png         Nodule/Mass
38694  081d1700020b6bf0099f1e4d8aeec0f3.png        Lung Opacity
50141  ff8ef73390f04480aba0be7810ef94cf.png          No finding
233    253d35b7096d0957bd79cfb4b1c954e1.png          No finding
2166   1951e0eba7c68aa1fbd6d723f19ee7c4.png  Pleural thickening
```

I use image generator

```
# Create a train generator
train_generator = train_dataGen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = train,
                                                directory = 'my_directory', 
                                                x_col = 'Images',
                                                y_col = 'Class',
                                                class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                # target_size = (256, 256),
                                                batch_size = 32)
```

I tried something dumb, but obviously did not work.

```
# Create an instance
oversample = SMOTE()

# Oversample
train_ovsm, valid_ovsm = oversample.fit_resample(train_ovsm, valid_ovsm)
```

Gives me an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '954984f75efe6890cfa45d0784a3a1e6.png'
```

Appreciate tips and good tutorials, cannot find anything so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answer satisfies you or not, but here is my thought. If I were you, I wouldn't try to balance it in the way you're trying it now. IMO, that's not the proper way. Your main concern is this [VinBigData](https://www.kaggle.com/c/vinbigdata-chest-xray-abnormalities-detection/data) is **highly imbalanced** and you're not sure how to address it properly.

Here are some first approaches all would adopt to address this issue in this competition.

```
- External dataset 
- Heavy and meaningful augmentation
- Modified the loss function
```

#### External Datasets

- NIH Chest X-rays : [Data](https://www.kaggle.com/nih-chest-xrays/data)
- SIIM-ACR Pneumothorax Segmentation : [Data](https://www.kaggle.com/c/siim-acr-pneumothorax-segmentation/overview)
- OSIC Pulmonary Fibrosis Progression : [Data](https://www.kaggle.com/c/osic-pulmonary-fibrosis-progression)
- RSNA Pneumonia Detection Challenge : [Data](https://www.kaggle.com/c/rsna-pneumonia-detection-challenge/overview)
- Chest X-Ray Images (Pneumonia) : [Data](https://www.kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/chest-xray-pneumonia)

What you need to do, collect all **possible external samples** from these datasets, combine them and make new datasets. It may take time but it worth it.

### Medical Image Augmentation

We all know augmentation is one of the key strategies for deep learning model training. But it would make sense to choose the right augmentation. [Here](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations#medical-imaging) are some demonstrations. The main intuition is to try not to destroy sensitive information. Be careful on that.

### Class Loss Weighting

You can modify the loss function to weight the predicted score. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48700950/9215780) is a detailed explanation of this topic.

Comment: Thanks for your time! This is a school project and we do different things. I am working on suggested steps too, but I want to know for future anyway how to oversample image data.

Comment: Oh, I see. Learning purpose can be good but as far as I can tell, using those over-sampling techniques you won't get any -wow- results from the trained model. -)